# How can I fix Authentication Failed error in Google Merchants while fetching the feed?

Tags: google, feeds

When I fetching the feed in my Google merchants Center, it shows below error:

Global feed issues
1 ERROR: Authentication failed..
Download failed due to authentication error. Please check username and password in your feed configuration and try again.
[image]

My feed was working properly but it shows this error today, does anybody know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After a hard job, finally I find the reason and solution for above error and here I want to share it with others.
The reason for above error was *blocking the crawl IP by firewall* in the Cloudflare and it is not related to *username and password in our feed configuration*. If you face same error, first check the firewall setting in server and your Cloudfare. If the IPs from which the Google Merchant is trying to connect has been blocked, you face above error while fetching your feed and you need to add this IP to your whitelist or unblock it. Also you can check your geographically block list too, if you block USA, you may face this problem, because Google Merchants IPs change periodically and you will face this error before indexing and recognizing the new IPs by Cloudflare. 
My problem was blocking USA in Cloudfalre and Google Merchants IPs changed last week, and the new IP was not indexing by Cloudflare as a Google crawls so it cannot reach our server.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Nader. We've been getting this persistently within the past week or so, and had the hunch it could be due to CF blocking Google IPs. But since Google keeps changing them here and there, we'd be facing the same situation after a while again. Were you able to resolve this using hostname or do you just keep unblocking certain IP ranges?

Comment: This started for us 2-15-19 I think, and since the feed items just expired taking our Google Shopping Ads down, we just discovered the issue.  Same exact scenario - no auth required for feed, but getting auth error.  Site uses cloudflare.  We can fetch the product feed XML just fine with the browser on our own IP.